Do I need to write an _init() for my Resources?
When I create my own Resource class in gdscript, I feel like I need to create a boilerplate _init() function or it won't serialize correctly. This function is annoying to write and brittle to future changes. Creating your own resources includes a warning:
extends Resource

@export var health: int
@export var sub_resource: Resource
@export var strings: PackedStringArray

# Make sure that every parameter has a default value.
# Otherwise, there will be problems with creating and editing
# your resource via the inspector.
func _init(p_health = 0, p_sub_resource = null, p_strings = []):
    health = p_health
    sub_resource = p_sub_resource
    strings = p_strings

But maybe the warning only means if you implement _init() then you need default values. (If so, I don't understand why their examples need it.)
I've had issues editing and duplicating my resources, but I'm not sure if that's because I completely omitted implementing _init() or just some misclicks. Is there a definitive answer for when/why do you need _init()?

No, you do not need to implement _init.
You can implement _init for ease of use, since it allows you to pass values on construction. But it is not necessary.
The warning is there because Godot expect to be able to call _init without parameters. So if your _init has any, they must be optional (i.e. a default value is given), otherwise Godot will fail to initialize resource instance, so loading them won't work.
Once Godot initialized the instance, the load process will set the properties by name (the equivalent of using set). That is, it does not rely on _init to populate the resource.

No, there is no definitive guide to when or why to use _init. But I can tell you a bit about my cases...
Looking at my code, I implement _init mostly on classes that extend RefCounted directly. These are classes that only make sense in runtime (are not meant, and do not have the means to be serialized, stored or transferred over the network).
I do have some custom resource type with _init. Because, either:

They need some of those RefCounted objects to work. 1 case.
They are doing some trickery with the filesystem to load additional data. 1 case.
I will often be creating them with particular values decided from code, and I wanted the convenience of _init (in my case this is a resource intended to show in the Inspector, but usually the user does not need to replace it, just edit it). 3 cases.

This is 5 custom resource types out of 104 in my current code base. The rest do not have _init, and it is not an issue.
